# Cannot get it correct when is use Session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have set a session in one method and I want to check in another method, if the user session then user can redirect.

```
public function validate_credentials(){ //function for validation of users_credentials

           $this->load->helper('url');



           $this->load->library('form_validation');



           $this->load->model('membership_model');



           $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

           if($query) //if credential validated

           {
                    $data1 = array(
                   'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                   'is_logged_in' => true );

                    $this->session->set_userdata($data1);

                    redirect('site/members_area');


           }

           else{

               $this->home();
           }


       }}
```

and i want to be able to use session in a different method below

```
  function get_student(){

$is_logged_in = $this->session->set_userdata('is_logged_in');

    if(isset($is_logged_in)){
        $studentID = $this->input->get('var1');

        $this->load_view($studentID);

        $this->load->model('fetch_student');  //model for fetching student profile data


        $data['student_prof'] = $this->fetch_student->get_profile($studentID);

        $data['main_content']='student/student_profile';

        $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
    }
        else{

            $this->_404();
        }   



}
```

Comment: Have you load session libraries in autoload?

Answer (score 0):

Have your load session library in application/config/autoload.php ??

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Actually, I didn't understood what want to write in get_student function but i think this is the way you want.

```
function get_student(){
   $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
   if($is_logged_in != ''){
      //your code goes here
   }
}
```

Comment: what i want is to validate that the user has login in the other method before being directed to the view

Answer (score 0):

You should set and get session like this
**In method 1**

```
$this->session->set_userdata('is_logged_in','TRUE');
```

**In method 2**

```
$user = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
if($user != "")
{
//your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public function validate_credentials(){ //function for validation of users_credentials

```
       $this->load->helper('url');



       $this->load->library('form_validation');



       $this->load->model('membership_model');



       $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

       if($query) //if credential validated

       {
                $data1 = array(
               'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
               'is_logged_in' => TRUE );

                $this->session->set_userdata($data1);

                redirect('site/members_area');


       }

       else{

           $this->home();
       }


   }}
```

New Function will be:

```
    public function members_area(){
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
       ///Your coding will be her
     }
    else{
       redirect('controller/login');
      }
   }

function logout(){
  $this->session->unset_userdata('is_logged_in');
  redirect('controller/login');
}
```